# Folders for checked SVN repositories not showing green, red tick icons

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2012-r2, visualsvn-server

I have set up VisualSVN Server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual server on Amazon Web Services EC2. A simple repository was created and hosted.

I also checked out the repository via TortoiseSVN Client to a folder on the C drive on the EC2 instance.

The folder does not have the green tick icon on it indicating it is a SVN repository as it should be.

How to make the SVN icons shown on folder icon?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [TortoiseSVN FAQ | Overlay icons](https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotshowing).

> indicating it is a SVN repository

Note that it is not a repository. It is a working copy.